# ¿Cómo crear un enlace que caduque para la autenticación de una dirección email?

Tags: nodemailer, enlace

Necesito confirmar la dirección de correo electrónico de un usario una vez se registre en el sitio web, pero no sé como crear el enlace que llega en el correo para lo que clickeen.

```
function EnviarCorreoConfirmacion(asunto, mensaje, correo, linktrue, linkfalse, callback) {
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: correo_origen,
        pass: password_origen
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: correo,
    to: "alternetvpn@gmail.com",
    subject: "Confirmar tu cuenta en AlternetVPN",
    text: " Confirma tu correo electrónico accediendo al siguiente link " + linktrue "Si no has realizado ninguna operación, haz click aquí: " + linkfalse 
};

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    console.log(msg_str_altervpn_ini);
    if (error) {
        console.log(msg_str_mail_error + msg_str_mail_respu + error);
        callback(true);
    } else {
        console.log(msg_str_mail_envia + msg_str_mail_respu + info.response);
        callback(false);
    }
    console.log(msg_str_altervpn_fin);
});
};
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: @Osleynin Mambell Ramos podrias agregar tu codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente se genera una cadena random que envías como parámetro en la url de validación, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $r = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 25);
    $linktrue = "http://dominio.ltd/?r=" . $r;
?>
```

y la guardas en la base de datos junto al usuario.

El usuario recibe el correo y al hacer click, tu recoges la cadena y la buscas en la base de datos, a groso modo y sin tener en cuenta SQL Injection:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["r"]))
        $r = $_POST["r"];
    $result = $mysqli->query(sprintf("SELECT uid FROM table WHERE r = '%s';", $r));
?>
```

Si la encuentras, marcas la cuenta como válida. Adicionalmente se suelen poner fechas de caducidad por seguridad y algunos gestores como Drupal, te dejan la cuenta ya logeada y el enlace es de un sólo uso. No te lo cuento todo para que disfrutes un poco.

Comment: Hola @OsleyninMambellRamos , si esta respuesta te sirvió de ayuda, márcala como aceptada pulsando en la marca de la parte superior izquierda de la misma.